Visa Requirements Bolivia
I am an Ethiopian citizen planning to travel to Bolivia via Istanbul and Brazil on connecting flights with one PNR (Passenger Name Record). According to IATA, I have the options for an eVisa and visa on arrival. However, when I attempt to apply for an eVisa, the Bolivian system indicates that I do not need an eVisa for tourism purposes.
